# Ionic 3 open external URL where URLs are set by an array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to open an external url in the device's browser by using the InAppBrowser plugin. My code as follows:

`home.ts`

```
openPage(url)
  {
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions =
    {
      zoom: 'no',
      hardwareback: 'no'
    }
    const browser = this.InAppBrowser.create(url, '_self', options);
    browser.show();
  }
```

And for the `home.html`

```
<button ion-button full (click)="openPage({{article.url}})">Read more</button>
```

Now, `{{article.url}}` is the URL I got from the array, it is supposed to set the URL of the button automatically to whatever `article.url` is supposed to be. However, the problem I am facing now is that doing `{{article.url}}` will give interpolation errors, while leaving `{{}}` out will give `_co.openPage is not a function` error. How do I proceed?

**EDIT:**

The rest of `home.ts` as follow

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  news: any;
  articels: string[];
  errorMessage: string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public rest:RestProvider, private InAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {
    this.getNews();
  }

  getNews() {
    this.rest.getNews()
    .then(result => {
      this.news = result;
      this.articels = this.news.articles;
      console.log(this.news.articles[0]);
    });
  }
  openPage(url)
  {
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions =
    {
      zoom: 'no',
      hardwareback: 'no'
    }
    const browser = this.InAppBrowser.create(url, '_self', options);
    browser.show();
  }


}
```

`home.html` as follow

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Recent News
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let article of articels">
      <ion-item>
          <h2>{{article.author}}</h2>
          <p>{{article.publishedAt}}</p>
        </ion-item>
          <img src="{{article.urlToImage}}">
          <ion-item>
              <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
              <p>{{article.description}}</p>
            </ion-item>
            <button ion-button full (click)="openPage(article.url)">Read more</button>
    <ion-card-content>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <p>Powered by NEWS API</p>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: For me,  leaving `{{}}` out does not generate `_co.openPage is not a function` error. Can you share that part of codes?

Comment: @HyuckKang Which part do you need?

Comment: I think it is good to share the whole code which have that component.

Comment: @HyuckKang Added the rest of the code

Comment: Firstly, your **articels: string[];** is wrong. It should be **articels: any[];**. Secondly, I cannot still generate your issue. To me, no error ocuurs.

Comment: @HyuckKang Apparently that solved the problem. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually, I did not know that kinds of mistakes invoke the error you got. Anyway, it is good to solve your issue.